# Generators for permutation groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, permutation-groups

Consider (e.g.) the full permutation group $G=S_6$. A valid set of generators and equations for $G$ is $r^6=m^2=(rm)^5=1$. I say this system has width $3$ (because there are $3$ equations), length $10$ (because there are $10$ generators in $(rm)^5$ - arguably, $m$ as a mirror causes no "load" in which case the length would be $6$) and height $6$ (for the exponent $6$).
What is the generator set with minimum height or length or width or (best) everything at the same time? How do I find it in the general case?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. The group defined by the presentation $\langle r,m \mid r^6=m^2=(rm)^5=1 \rangle$ is not $S_6$; it is an infinite group.

Comment: Width and length both seem relatively simple to define in terms of a presentation, but height doesn't - what if the presentation was $rrrrrr = mm = rmrmrmrmrm = 1$? Or $rrmmrrrr = mm = rmrmrmrmrm = 1$ How would you get $6$ out of that?

Comment: Additionally, given any finite presentation, you can find a presentation of "length" $2$ (but with high width and many generators). So trying to get a "(best) everything at the same time" doesn't work; you will have to specify some single thing you want to minimize.

Comment: @user44191 Both you and Francesco Polizzi in his answer are talking about presentations, but there is no mention of presentations in the question, and the example given is not a presentation for $S_6$, so I am not at all sure that the question is about presentations.

Comment: @DerekHolt "set of generators and equations" seems like a description of a presentation to me. I was focusing more on the (partial) definitions than the specific group, as they seem to be applicable to any presentation.

Comment: @DerekHolt: The OP said "A valid set of generators and equations for $G$ is...", so I assumed it was a presentation (without thinking so much if this was true)

Comment: @DerekHolt: It isn't? Oops. When I looked for matrix representations for irreps, those equations were sufficient to derive the entries. Which equation(s) do I have to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a well-known [Coxeter presentation](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Presentation_theory_of_symmetric_groups) of $S_n$ having height $3$.

Regarding presentations with short width and length (again, in the general case) you can have a look at the paper

Bray, J. N.; Conder, M. D. E.; Leedham-Green, C. R.; O’Brien, E. A.: [*Short presentations for alternating and symmetric groups*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-2011-05231-1), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. **363**, No. 6, 3277-3285 (2011), [ZBL1223.20023](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1223.20023).

For instance, the authors show hot to construct a presentation in two generators having width $O(\log n)$ and length $O(\log^2 n)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to your question in your comment rather than to the original question. With a bit of computer experimentation, I found that
$$S_6 \cong \langle m,r | r^6=m^2=(rm)^5 = (mr^2mr^{-2})^2 = (mrmr^{-1})^3 = 1 \rangle.$$
You can reduce that to three relations, by combining the first two, and the final two to give

$$S_6 \cong \langle m,r | r^6=m^2,\ (rm)^5 = 1,\ (mr^2mr^{-2})^2 = (mrmr^{-1})^3 \rangle.$$

Since the Schur Multiplier of $S_6$ is nontrivial (it has order 2), every presentation must have at least pone more relation than generator, so you cannot define $S_6$ with two relations.

Comment: Converting to the Coxeter presentation, I got the same result (but didn't know which of the additional equations are needed - THX!). I guess my "technique" I used to get a matrix 5-dim irrep of S6 automagically fulfilled the other equations, thus my error.